# Why is apache allowing access to ownCloud directory outside of DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache, debian, virtualhost, owncloud

The setup...

I am experiencing an odd issue with my Debian installation of ownCloud. I have set my DocumentRoot as /var/www/docroot/ and made it accessible only via ssl.

I have installed ownCloud using apt-get and its default location is /var/www/owncloud

There is no directory or symlink named owncloud inside /var/www/docroot/

I do not have a VirtualHost (that I can see) that allows access to /var/www/owncloud

The problem...

When I go to myserver.com/owncloud, it actually serves up the owncloud directory. Clearly I have missed something, but I am not seeing what it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owncloud package includes its own config file: /etc/apache2/conf-available/owncloud.conf, the configuration that makes /var/www/owncloud available is probably there.

You can disable this file using a2disconf and then set up your own customized config in the virtualhost file.